# Why initialize the ListNode twice here?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

Question: You are given two non-empty linked lists representing two non-negative integers. The digits are stored in reverse order and each of their nodes contain a single digit. Add the two numbers and return it as a linked list.

You may assume the two numbers do not contain any leading zero, except the number 0 itself.

Here is my solution in JAVA to this question:

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    public ListNode addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
        ListNode dummy = new ListNode(0);
        ListNode l3 = dummy;
        int carry = 0;

        while(l1 != null && l2 != null){
            int digitValue = (l1.val + l2.val + carry)%10;
            carry = (l1.val + l2.val + carry)/10;

            ListNode newNode = new ListNode(digitValue);

            l3.next = newNode;
            l3 = newNode;

            l2 = l2.next;
            l1 = l1.next;
        }

        while(l1 != null){
            int digitValue = (l1.val + carry)%10;
            carry = (l1.val + carry)/10;

            ListNode newNode = new ListNode(digitValue);

            l3.next = newNode;
            l3 = newNode;

            l1 = l1.next;
        }

        while(l2 != null){
            int digitValue = (l2.val + carry)%10;
            carry = (l2.val + carry)/10;

            ListNode newNode = new ListNode(digitValue);

            l3.next = newNode;
            l3 = newNode;

            l2 = l2.next;
        }

        if(carry != 0 ){
            ListNode newNode = new ListNode(carry);
            l3.next = newNode;
            l3 = newNode;
        }

        return dummy.next;
    }
}
```

However, Why codes has to be as

```
ListNode dummy = new ListNode(0);
ListNode l3 = dummy;
```

, rather than just: **"listNode l3 = new ListNode(0);"** I know it's wrong. If I use this code, my answer will return "[]". I don't understand why this happens?

Comment: Your return value is dummy.next. If you eliminate dummy, what will you return? l3.next? l3 gets re-assigned in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just you need to hold the head of the result that you need to return so that we can print it. if you do like "listNode l3 = new ListNode(0);", and update reference of l3 then at the end of the function l3 is the tail of the list.

what you are doing here is to create a dummy node reference as head of link list and create another reference l3 to modify the list

```
ListNode dummy = new ListNode(0);
ListNode l3 = dummy;
```